# json increments one id but displays all ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

i am using json for like button. when users clicks it correctly increases the like count and stores in database for corresponding id  but it shows increment for all ids in browser which is wrong. i want to display for only id where users has liked but it shows for all.

test url is  http://way2enjoy.com/app/check/test/indexp.php

indexp.php file is

```
<?php


include('/home/xxx/con.php');


   $query="Select * from users_jokes order by id desc limit 10";
   $result=mysql_query($query);


?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxSubmit = function(formEl) {

                var url = $(formEl).attr('action');


                var comment=document.getElementById("jokes_comment").value;
                var joke_id=document.getElementById("joke_id_hidden").value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data:{
                        'action':'addComment',
                        'comment':comment,
                        'joke_id':joke_id
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type:'POST',
                    success: function(result) {

                            console.log(result);
                            $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            data:{
                            'action':'getLastComment',
                            'joke_id':joke_id
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type:'POST',
                            success: function(result) {                             
                            $('#jokes_comment').val("");
                            console.log(result[0].description);
                            $("#header ul").append('<li>'+result[0].description+'</li>');                           

                            },
                            error: function(){
                            alert('failure');


                    }
                });

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('failure');


                    }
                });

                // return false so the form does not actually
                // submit to the page
                return false;
            }

        var ajaxLike=function()
        {
            var joke_id=document.getElementById("joke_id_hidden").value;
            // setup the ajax request
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'likeskk.php',
                data:{
                    'action':'increment_like',
                    'joke_id':joke_id
                    },
                dataType: 'json',
                type:'POST',
                success: function(result) 
                {

                        $.ajax(
                    {

                        url: 'likeskk.php',
                        data:{
                            'action':'display_like',
                            'joke_id':joke_id
                            },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type:'POST',
                        success: function(result)
                        {

                            console.log(result);
                                               $("label[for='like_counter']").text(result.likes);


                        },
                        error: function(result)
                        {
                            alert("error 2");

                        },

                    });
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert('failure');

                }
            });

           return false;
        }
        </script>

<p>commnet list</p>
<div id="header">
<ul id="commentlist" class="justList">
<?php
 $query="Select * from comment where joke_id='2'";
   $result=mysql_query($query);

   while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $cont = $data['description'];
    ?>
    <li><?php echo $cont;
    ?></li>
    <?php
   }
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php

?>
<form  method="post" action="processkk.php" onSubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this);">
<input type=text id="jokes_comment" name="jokes_comment">

</input>
<input type="submit" value="comment">

</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php 
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $data['id'];
    $cont = $data['content'];
    $likes = $data['likes'];
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $cont;?></p>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ;?>" id="joke_id_hidden">
    <p><button  onClick="ajaxLike();">Like</button> <label for="like_counter"><?php echo $likes;?></label></p>
    <?php }
?>

</body>
</html>



likeskk.php 

    <?php


     include('/home/xxxxxxx/con.php');



         $action=$_POST['action'];
         if($action=="increment_like")
         {
             $joke_id=$_POST['joke_id'];
            $query="update users_jokes set likes =likes+1 where id='".$joke_id."'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);

            // setup our response "object"

            $retVal=array("Success"=>"true");
             print json_encode($retVal);

         }
          if($action=="display_like")
         {
            $joke_id=$_POST['joke_id'];
            $query = "select likes from users_jokes where id = '$joke_id'";
            $qry = mysql_query($query);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
                $likes = $rows['likes'];
            }

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            // print json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));
            print json_encode(array('success'=>'true','likes'=>$likes));


         }

    ?>
```

when i click on one like all like increases.  when i post comment on one id it appended and displays in all id

Comment: Please clean up your code, post the javascript separately and post the php that handles the jquery post separately.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste it.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function clickCounter(element)
    {
        element.value = parseInt(element.value) + 1;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="clickCounter(this)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same id. id must be unique

```
<input type="hidden" value="4638" id="joke_id_hidden">
```

Comment: for every post it is different. please check

Comment: can u plz delete ur answer

Comment: No, they are all same. Here is the screenshot. http://i.hizliresim.com/mLnLrR.png

Comment: I try to help you. Search for joke_id_hidden in your html code. You will see in 10 different lines

Comment: in this link i changed the id http://way2enjoy.com/app/check/test/indexp1.php but then how to change the javascript. for each row i cant have complete javascript     var joke_id=document.getElementById("joke_id_hidden<?php echo $id ;?>").value;

Comment: I sent another answer. Just copy and paste it. You will understand the structure.

Comment: thanks , but in my case how to change javascript id.

Comment: You will not use id. Because "id" can be used for only one element. You have to send "this" parameter when function is called. Last code that I sent is more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a hidden input for each entry you could use a dataset on the button itself with the corresponding ID. When the button is clicked the javscript function could read that dataset value and use that in the ajax POST request. So, as an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Like the jokes...</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id='bttns'>
            <?php
                /* pseudo generate some jokes with buttons and labels to emulate your page */
                for( $i=1; $i < 20; $i++ ){

                    $random=rand(1,20);

                    echo "
                    <p>Funny joke...[{$i}]</p>
                    <input type='button' value='Like' data-id='$i' />
                    <label class='counter'>{$random}</label>";
                }
            ?>
        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var col=document.querySelectorAll('#bttns input[type=\"button\"]');

            for( var n in col )if(col[n].nodeType==1)col[n].onclick=function(e){

                var el=typeof(e.target)!='undefined' ? e.target : e.srcElement;
                var label=el.nextSibling.nextSibling;
                var id=el.dataset.id;

                label.innerHTML=parseInt( label.innerHTML )+1;

                alert( 'use ajax to POST this id: '+id );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I should add perhaps that the ajax callback function would be the place to update the value of `likes` for each joke rather than as here - it's just example code showing how you could do away with hidden fields and the problem of duplicate ids.